# How to take screenshots on protected medias?

Tags: macos, screenshot

I saw this awesome movie that I watched on DVD and wanted to take a screen shot of it, but when I did, it was transparent. I could only see my desktop taken but not the movie. Is there a specific program or hack that could let me take a screen shot of that content? I tried every screen shot software, but still leaves it transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try VLC player, under Menu->Video you should see 'Take Snapshot'. As far as I remember it worked for me while I had the same problem (though on windows).

Here is  the download link:
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/#download

Answer (score 1):

Use proper player, such as KMPlayer. In there you can do PrintScreen or choose a variety of options:

[image]